# Are the fields of a final member variable changing values?

Tags: java, final

For example, we have a final member variable type Cat. Inside the constructor we initialize this variable with a specific instance of a Cat myCat. If we change the myCat.age field does it changes at the final member variable too or it keeps the same value (age) as the time initialized?

```
public class Aclass {
    final Cat myCat;
    
    public Aclass(Cat myCat) {
        this.myCat = myCat;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check description of `final` keyword here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/final-keyword-in-java/. Here is what happens: If the final variable is a reference, this means that the variable cannot be re-bound to reference another object, but the internal state of the object pointed by that reference variable can be changed i.e. you can change field values of the class instance assigned to the final field.

Comment: Fundamentally, you're missing the distinction between a variable and an object.  'final' is a property of the variable, not of any object the variable might refer to.

Answer (score 3):

Writing `final Cat myCat;` means you can't change which `Cat` object `myCat` references, once the constructor has finished running.  But you can certainly call methods of the `Cat`, like `myCat.setAge(15);`, subject to the usual access rules.  So the fields of the `Cat` object can certainly change their values.  The only thing that can't change is which `Cat` you have.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change `cat` value like `cat = newcat`, because cat is final. You can change properities like `cat.age(newvalue)` because there is a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> If we change the `myCat.age` field does it changes at the `final` member variable too or it keeps the same value (`age`) as the time initialized?

This presumably refers to some code like this:

```
   Cat murgatroyd = ...
   Aclass ac = new Aclass(murgatroyd);
   ac.myCat.age = 21;
```

where `Aclass` is as per your question and `Cat` has a (non-final, non-private) integer field called `age`.  The `myCat` field is `final`, as per your code.

---

The `age` value changes.

Declaring a variable to be `final` does not make the object that the variable refers to constant.  The only thing that `final` modifier "freezes" is the reference value held in the variable itself.

---

The reference in `myCat` doesn't change.

An assignment to `myCat.age` is not an (attempted) assignment to the `myCat` variable itself.  This assignment wouldn't change the `myCat` variable (to point to a different `Cat`) even if `myCat` was not declared as `final`.  That's not what field assignment means in Java ...